# ffmpeg PTS calculation

Tags: ffmpeg, pts

i im using ffmpeg to save stream in memory and then restream to my html5 web page...i would like to know how can i manually calculate PTS value like xtream panel codes does have (PTS/Network Speed 1.00x or 1.34x or 0.94x)....i can't get output from ffmpeg because i im not saving output file to hdd so i need to caluclate it manually...

i got all information from memory chunk stream link pts_timebase and some others informations like bitrate, resolution etc...how can i manually calculate PTS like ffmpeg outputs when you save file from ffmpeg to HDD and then you get for example:

```
frame= 710 fps = 65 q=1.0 Lsize = 4974kB time=00:00:28.33 bitrate = 1437.9kbits/s speed = 2.61x
```

I would like to calculate manually this speed that in this example is 2.61x..what is the forumla to calulate this?

Thanks.

Comment: The speed is simply `duration of video processed / time taken`. So, if in 10 seconds, 16.5 seconds of the output is processed, then speed is `16.5 / 10` = `1.65x`. In the line you have shown, processing speed is `65 fps` and it looks like output framerate is `25 fps`, so speed is `65 / 25` = `2.6x`

Comment: Thanks....i was never guessed that easy formula...you save my time...so i can get from ffmpeg processed fps and divide from fps from video...so if my video fps is 23,976 and processed fps is 65 then speed is 2,71..thanks